# Would it make sense to recreate a string pool sort of thing for a fraction class?

Tags: java

I made an immutable fraction class (I think so, everything is final). I read that Strings have this "pool" where once "asd" is instantiated, all other references to "asd" would just point to the first. (if I understood that right) So would it make sense for me to recreate this "pool" as a super class which would contain all created fractions. There could be a static factory method that first checks the pool of existing fractions before it creates a new fraction?

```
    var a = new Fraction(3,4);
    var b = a;
    var c = new Fraction(3,2);
    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + (a == b)); // 3/4 3/4 true

    b = a.add(b);

    System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + (a == b)); // 3/4 3/2 false

    System.out.println(b + " " + c + " " + (b == c)); // 3/2 3/2 false (should be true but add() returns a new fraction)
```

Would this idea be worth doing i.e. would it be faster than instantiating new fractions with the same value on average?

Comment: It's probably far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: For this easy example, Fractions, it's not really worth it. You'd have to have some kind of fast, adaptive storage, and probably some measurement of when to flush some out of that storage to prevent memory leaks. Then you might have statistical analyses of which numbers are especially good to keep, you have to create estimates of what ranges of numbers you definitely do not want to keep etc. It's not that hard to implement, all in all, but it's a lot of work for no major gain. If, however, the problem is more complex, for example recursive like Fibonacci, primes, this might indeed get feasible

Comment: Yup, looks like I should stick to what I have at the moment, thanks for the advice guys! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hold *all* created fractions, then you have a memory leak. (Note that the `String` pool doesn't contain *all* created strings, just those which occur as literals in the source code, plus any which you call `.intern()` on yourself.)

It might make sense to have a cache of frequently-used fractions, say `Fraction(n, 1)` for a reasonable range of integers and `Fraction(n, m)` for a smaller range. But you have to weigh the savings of not creating new objects with the cost of checking if an object is already in the cache every time; the net gain is likely to be marginal at best, and possibly negative in many real applications, so you will want to test this with some suitable benchmark.

A simpler way is to provide some pre-made constants like `Fraction.ZERO`, `Fraction.ONE`, `Fraction.ONE_HALF`, `Fraction.ONE_THIRD` and so on. Then users of your API can refer to those constants rather than constructing new instances with literal values every time they need to use those common fractions. This is the approach taken by the standard library class [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html): there is no built-in pool or cache, but you can write `BigInteger.ZERO`, `BigInteger.ONE` or `BigInteger.TEN` instead of instantiating multiple copies of those common numbers.

Comment: Thanks for answering! :)